# How to classify segments of time series data

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, lstm

I have time series data being captured from the accelerometer of an android phone. I have added a class column so that I can label the class of the data. The data has a binary classification, 0 for false, and 1 for true. The time series data has continuous segments where the entire segment together should be classified as 1. I have highlighted the charted data to show the continuous sections of data I am classifying as 1. I would like to be able to label this training data and then provide new data to a trained model that can classify the data, and also tell where it starts and ends so I can pull out the start and stop time. From what I have read online, it seems that a LSTM neural net would be the right solution, but I am not sure how to build a model that can classify the continuous segments. Direction or simple examples anyone is aware of that shows how to use LSTM, or a more suitable model for this type of data to accomplish what I am trying to accomplish would be awesome. I am new to machine learning and attempting this project for my own learning/curiosity, so apologies for incorrect terminology or lack of knowledge.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

LSTMs are good feed to process sequential data. I suggest you read some examples of building a simple NN based on LSTM, for example in tensorflow. (http://wiki.pathmind.com/lstm, https://machinelearningmastery.com/gentle-introduction-long-short-term-memory-networks-experts/) plus you can read the docs or even ask chatGPT to write you some base LSTM network with description of all the parameters.

Second, I think in tour case you should chunk the data into little sequences of the size that can be classified as 1 or 0 and then design the output of a NN to be the size of the inputs. Let's say your input is 10 samples, so your output will also be 10 samples each corresponding to the value 0 or 1. The thing is to correctly define the training set and train the network properly.

Hope it was helpful,
good luck.